# WordPress: User with custom role cannot access wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

First of all I am a WordPress learner. So sorry if my code looks stupid!

I have created a custom theme with a custom user role. I am not developing any plugin.

In my fucntions.php file I have written the following code to create a User role. Users assigned to this role are supposed to login to the admin but only be able to access their Profile pages.

```
add_action('init', 'yrc_cst_register_role_customer_service_rep');

/**
 * Register new user role
 */

function yrc_cst_register_role_customer_service_rep() {

    $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $wp_roles->remove_role('subscriber');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('editor');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('contributor');
    $wp_roles->remove_role('author');

    $service_rep_caps = array(
        'read'              => false,
        'create_posts'      => false,
        'edit_posts'        => false,
        'edit_others_posts' => false,
        'publish_posts'     => false,
        'manage_categories' => false,
        'manage_options'    => false,
    );

    add_role('customer_service', __('Customer Service'), $service_rep_caps);
}
```

I have removed all roles except Administrator, because no other role is required for this portal. Administrator will only create Users with **Customer Service** role.

I have no third party plugin installed in the system.

Users with the custom role are able to login to the system through a custom login page which is working OK. But whenever they are trying to access their Profile page the following error message comes up:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

Is there anything like `'edit_profile' => true`?

I must be doing something wrong but my limited knowledge is not enough to figure this out. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think he neads 'read' => true

Comment: but then again - a subscriber is , by default, only allowed to access their profile page, right?

Comment: yeah - the role should only have 'read'

Comment: In that case do I need to add `'capabilities' => 'subscriber'`? Changing to `'read' => true` is not making any difference. Also for a custom role what is the right way to define the capability so that he can only access his profile page?

Comment: the capability "read" Allows access to Administration Panel options:
Dashboard and 
Users > Your Profile

Comment: You mean only `'read' => true` and nothing else?

Comment: everything else should be false

Comment: look at this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Subscriber

Comment: Thank you I will kook into the article. But in my code if I change rad to true and keep everything else to false (like I have now), the same error is coming up. And also if there is only `read`, will the user be able to edit his profile?

Comment: but the entire thing might be faster if you just use this plugin for it : https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/ - with this you can add new roles and control their capabilities

Comment: Thank you! But I want to code myself to learn how it actually works. :)

Comment: It works!! Thank you @Stender. :)

Comment: @SubrataSarkar, what made code to work suddenly, how did you finally resolved it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to do it like this :

This should clone the subscriber role capabilities and create your role for it.

```
add_action('init', 'CreatecloneRoleSubscriber');

function CreatecloneRoleSubscriber()
{
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $sub = $wp_roles->get_role('Subscriber');
    //Adding a 'new_role' with all subscriber caps
    $wp_roles->add_role('customer_service', 'Customer Service', $sub->capabilities);
}
```

EDIT : Read discussion in question comments

Comment: Clone - Great stuff!

Comment: This worked for me! But I needed to add `remove_role()` first and reapply the role to the user. Otherwise capabilities won't get updated.

Comment: @Skatox So, you removed the subscriber role?

Comment: @Stender No I removed customer_service (my own role) in order to update changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this solution which i consider really clean to enter wp-admin with a new role:

###### Add access cap to backend

Add the cap `view_admin_dashboard` & `read` to your new role.

###### Show the admin bar

Add this function to your wordpress.

```php
# functions.php

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', function () {

    if ( current_user_can( 'view_admin_dashboard' ) )
        return true;
    
    return false;

}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the manage_options to true in your case
But note that by allowing manage_options to true, those user will have access to other parts of dashboard as well

```
 $service_rep_caps = array(
    'read'              => false,
    'create_posts'      => false,
    'edit_posts'        => false,
    'edit_others_posts' => false,
    'publish_posts'     => false,
    'manage_categories' => false,
    'manage_options'    => true, // Most plugins and pages check for manage_options for checking access level to allow access to pages and settings.
);
```

Comment: Right, but according to requirement that is not allowed for a user with this role